# Why is ORDER BY necessary in this SQL statement

Tags: sql, database

This is leetcode question 613:

Write an SQL query to report the shortest distance between any two points from the Point table.

Here's the table schema:

```
Point
+-------------+------+
| Column Name | Type |
+-------------+------+
| x           | int  |
+-------------+------+
x is the primary key column for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the position of a point on the X-axis.
```

I thought this would be a straight forward application of the LEAD function with an offset of 1, so my answer was:

```
SELECT MIN(dist) as shortest
FROM    (SELECT ABS(x - LEAD(x, 1, NULL) OVER () ) AS dist
        FROM POINT) AS dist_table;
```

OVER () will cause LEAD to use all of the rows except the same row twice. However, this gave the wrong answer.

The only change from my answer to the right answer was using OVER(ORDER BY X) which makes no sense to me. The way I see it we would still be taking the distances of every row(minus the same rows). If someone could please explain, I'd be truly grateful. I've been pouring over articles to no help.

Comment: It makes no sense *without* the order, `Over` indicates the *window* into which the function operates and defines which row is the next row in a set of rows; a table is a set and a set has no order.

Comment: `lead` does not use all of the rows. It grabs the *next* row relative to the *current* row according to the order of that window.

Comment: I was under the impression that OVER () would use all the rows of the table when there was nothing inside the parenthesis. Is that not true?

Comment: @trincot OHhhhhhh.... So essentially I was just taking the distance of x and a single other row? And there was no way to tell which "other row" I was taking because as Stu says "a table is a set and a set has no order." Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, the distance is with a single other row. Which is quite efficient, provided that the next row is the next according to the numerical ordering. Without imposing an ordering, you don't control the ordering that will be used. This can be engine-dependent, dependent on previous edits to the table, and other factors. In other words: don't rely on order when you don't explicitly impose an order.

Comment: @trincot OOOOOOOOHHHHHH my brain feels smarter lmao. THANK YOU SO MUCH :-)

Comment: So now I have a question for you: can you do it without using `ABS`?

Comment: @trincot We can ORDER By DESC this way the values will always be positive anyway. Is the benefit here that we don't have to do an extra operation? I think asymptotically we'd still have O(nlogn) time since we have a sorting function (i.e. ORDER BY).

Comment: Yes you got it that right. Reversing the terms would also be an option.